# How to find the endpoint of a vector giving its length and startpoint

Tags: math, vector, language-agnostic, geometry

I have a vector V starting at x,y with velocity dirx,diry (for example 2,3). I want to know the cooridinates of the end point of the vector if its length (i guess the norm) was equal to 40 for example.

Sorry, my math knowledge it quite low, many thanks in advance

Comment: Vectors don't have any velocity, as well as starting points. Could you add an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalize direction vector, if needed:

```
Len = Sqrt( dirx^2 + diry^2 )
dx = dirx / Len
dy = diry / Len
```

then find endpoint:

```
end_x = x0 + 40 * dx
end_y = y0 + 40 * dy
```

Comment: Thanks much appreciated, now using your solution i'm getting an other issue....would you be able to help please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28765190/wrong-repositioning-circle-after-collision-with-segment-with-a-vector-algorythm