# Wrong repositioning circle after collision with segment with a vector algorithm

Tags: math, vector, 2d, collision-detection

In a 2D game, i'm trying to repositionate a circle after it passed through a segment. Taking the picture as example situation, i need to reposition back the circle so that B will become the tangent point on the circle.

[image]

The informations that i have are:

- x,y of the circle
- Radius of the circle
- dirx, diry: Direction of x,y the circle is having
- Distance between A and B

What i'm doing is to calculate the coordinates of point C, then coordinates of point B, and then subtract vector AB from AC (radius), and repositionate x,y back of -BC.

There is something wrong in the algorithm because after that the orthogonal distance between the center and the line is never exactly like the radius.

```
Len = Sqrt( dirx^2 + diry^2 )
dx = dirx / Len
dy = diry / Len
// these should be coordinates of point C
tangX = x + radius * dx
tangY = y + radius * dy
// these should be coordinates of point B
wrongX = x + distance* dx
wrongY = y + distance* dy
//these should be vector BC
BCx = tangX - wrongX;
BCy = tangY - wrongY;
// now i reposition the center back of BC
x = x - BCx
y = y - BCy
```

The center is repositionated in the correct direction but never enough to match the distance AC.

In other words:
I want to move the center and make B to be the tangent point between the circle and the line. Let me explain you in other words the problem: as you can see length of AC is equal to my radius. The radius is 40. in my log, i print out the value of the distance between A and B. Taking the image as example such distance would be something like 30, after my algorithm i expect that AB is 40 (the radius, AC) but it's always an other number, never 40

Comment: To make a tangent, you have to provide direction of the line.

Comment: Thanks again for your attengion MBo. Do you mean to find the equation of the line? The direction of the line for me is the initial dirx, diry

Comment: Sorry probably you mean the line that the circle went trough...in this case i know startx and starty, stopx and stopy of the line...then i'm able to calculate the vector i guess (stopx - startx, stopy - starty). How should i proceed?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the problem. What do you mean "but never enough to match the distance AC"?

Comment: the point C is never the point where the line is tangent to the circle...The line is always or too inside the circle or too outside, never tangent

Comment: @Nadir I've reviewed the equations of your deduction and they are correct. If there is an error it must be elsewhere. What still confuses me from your previous comment is "`C` is never the point where the line is tangent to the circle." Do you mean to the circle with center `(x - BCx, y - BCy)`? Because that center corresponds to a circle that makes `B` the intersection of the ray `AC` with the new circle and the ortogonal line the tangent.

Comment: Sorry, problem formulation is not clear

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia yes, that's what i want but i'm not achieving! I want to move the center and make B to be the tangent point between the circle and the line. Let me explain you in other words the problem: as you can see length of AC is equal to my radius. The radius is 40. in my log, i print out the value of the distance between A and B. Taking the image as example such distance would be something like 30, after my algorithm i expect that AB is 40 (the radius, AC) but it's always an other number, never 40

Comment: What "other numbers" are you getting?

Comment: it depends on the initial situation, on how much the circle went through the line. They can be number between 35 and 41...but never 40 as i'm expected

Comment: @Nadir Just to be sure... you are using `float` or `double` as your data type for all variables and never `int`, right?

Comment: eigenchris, yes float and double are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is relatively easy to solve, if formulated appropriately. It seems a simple case of collision detection, where you're seeking to adjust the object's position after detecting the collision. The intuitive way to frame it is: you have an event telling you your object crossed a boundary. Its last motion vector is `(dirX, dirY)` and you're given the `delta` your object crossed beyond the boundary. All you need to do is to move your object backwards, the same delta it crossed beyond the boundary, along the same motion vector.

And instead of reasoning about the problem in terms of tangent points, you can simply reason about it in terms of the center coordinates of the object itself.

Now, the following parameters are given input:

- let `x, y` be the last coordinates of your object's center and `r` its radius
- let `(dirX, dirY)` be your motion vector
- let `alpha` be the angle of your motion vector to the x axis (you can compute it from the motion vector itself)
- let `delta` be the distance crossed beyond the boundary

The problem's resolution reduces to the following:

[image]

And here's an executable code sample in python 2 that implements and tests that solution:

```py
from math import sin, cos, atan, fabs as abs, sqrt, pow
from collections import namedtuple

# utility types and functions
Disk = namedtuple('Disk', 'x y radius')
MotionVector = namedtuple('MotionVector', 'x y')

def sqr(d):
    return pow(d, 2)


# the actual implementation of the solution
def reposition_disk(disk, delta, motion_vector):
    # we start by computing the angle to the x axis of the motion vector
    alpha = atan(motion_vector.y / motion_vector.x)

    # then we compute the displacement we should apply
    # to our object along both axes

    dX = cos(alpha) * delta
    dY = sin(alpha) * delta

    # and we update the object's coordinates
    return Disk(disk.x - dX, disk.y - dY, disk.radius)


# a test method to exercise our implementation
def test_reposition_disk():
    # initialiasing our disk at a position where it is supposed
    # to have crossed a boundary
    disk = Disk(80, 70, 40)

    # the disk was moving along the following motion vector:
    motion_vector = MotionVector(10, -5)

    delta = 5

    updated = reposition_disk(disk, delta, motion_vector)

    # now we need to compute the coordinates of the 
    # point of the boundary the disk should have stopped at

    alpha = atan(motion_vector.y / motion_vector.x)
    bX = disk.x + (disk.radius - delta) * cos(alpha)
    bY = disk.y + (disk.radius - delta) * sin(alpha)

    # and finally we have to assert that the distance from
    # the object's new coordinates to the boundary is equal
    # to its radius

    distance = sqrt(sqr(updated.x - bX ) + sqr(updated.y - bY))
    print('Distance to boundary : %f' % distance)
    assert abs(distance - disk.radius) < 0.01


test_reposition_disk()
```

**Addendum**

I went through the code you pasted and unless I am mistaken, there is a problem with the logic through which, you are checking for collision and computing the distance from the center of the circle to the intersecting line. An accurate implementation of that logic implies solving a quadratic equation (check this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228841/how-do-i-calculate-the-intersections-of-a-straight-line-and-a-circle) for future reference) to find out whether the line intersects the circle. Then to compute the distance you'll have to solve an equation based on the dot product of the direction vector of the intersecting line, and the orthogonal line passing through the center of the circle.

Here's a python snippet illustrating the first part (figuring out whether or not the line intersects the circle) and loosely following the steps detailed in the above link:

```py
Line = namedtuple('Line', 'x1 y1 x2 y2')

# currying the square out of pow
def sqr(d):
    return pow(d, 2)


# function to compute the line equation
# out of the coordinates of a couple of
# points
def coords_to_affine(line):
    # y = hx + j
    h = (line.y2 - line.y1) / (line.x2 - line.x1)
    j = y1 - (h * x1)
    return (h, j)


# function to compute the quadratic equation
# parameters
def compute_quadratic_params(disk, line):
    (h, j) = coords_to_affine(line)
    (p, q, r) = (disk.x, disk.y, disk.r)

    a = sqr(h) + 1
    b = 2 * ((h * j) - (h * q) - p)
    c = sqr(q) - sqr(r) + sqr(p) - (2 * (j * q)) + sqr(j)
    return (a, b, c)


# function to test whether a given circle
# intersects a line
def disk_intersects_line(a, b, c):
    # true if (b² - 4ac) >= 0
    return (sqr(b) - (4 * a * c)) >= 0
```

Comment: Many thanks for you smart answer, actually this has been the smoothest solution so far. Unfortunely you can see in my log that the value after the algorythm is never equal to the radius (radius is defines 40 at the moment). Sometimes there is a quite big difference. You can see the print of the distance value before the algorythm (when i detect collision) and after algorythm (after i repositionate the circle)

Comment: before: 38.052597
after: 40.04996871948242
before: 33.24154
after: 37.6961555480957
before: 37.01351
after: 39.824615478515625
before : 37.802116
after : 39.20458984375
before : 33.970577
after : 40.360870361328125
before : 28.653097
after : 37.58989334106445
before : 25.495098
after : 37.53664779663086
before : 21.84033
after : 39.0128173828125
before : 19.104973
after : 40.31128692626953
before : 29.15476
after : 39.20458984375

Comment: Can you please post the test data you're using in http://pastebin.com/ and link back here ? The math of this problem is pretty straightforward. And shouldn't result in such ambiguous results, unless the test data is inconsistent somewhere.

Comment: If you can also post whatever code you're using to run your tests. I'm suspecting this where the issue might actually be (either the test data or the test code).

Comment: What are the variables you're referring to as `distanza` and `distColl` ?

Comment: distColl is the distance calculated with math in isCollided routine. Basically is the distance between the center and the line. Distanza is (radius - distacoll) so the "too much" amount we will need to move back the center

Comment: Your `isCollided()` method is a bit hard to read and has high probability for buggy behaviour. I'm guessing this is where you're checking that a line crosses the circle. If yes you compute the distance from the center of the circle to the line. I'll get back on it later.

Comment: Yes, i check here whether i have collision and i have the distance between line to the center. Many thanks for trying helping me, let me know if you find out where the bug is

Comment: I updated my answer above with a suggestion on how to check for intersection. I don't think your implementation is accurate in that respect.

Comment: tomorrow i will check and study your addendum. In the meanwhile i really thank you for the interest, as you have been the only one to give some help, that's why you deserve the bounty and best answer. Thanks

Comment: I saw you gave an algorythm to check if there is intersection, but not the distance between circle and line, how can i get the distance, starting from your algorythm?

Comment: More important than the algorithm, is the math behind the problem you're trying to solve. The second part is another mathematical problem: distance between a point (the center of the disk) and a line (the intersecting line). And I gave you hints about solving it using the dot product of 2 perpendicular vectors.

Comment: Also if you want to make good use of stackoverflow, you need to put some effort in trying to understand the problem you're tackling first. Then when it comes to asking a question, you need to narrow the scope of your question, so as to allow people to focus on the real issue you're having. Also if you have an interest in games/graphics, you need to be comfortable in math and particularly linear algebra.